# Adding licensing support for Eclipse PDE

Tags: eclipse, licensing, editor, pde

I have built an eclipse plugin which basically makes writing Java GUI applications as easy as using a 4GL programming language (Oracle Forms, Visual Basic etc). The plugin generates no GUI code but rather metadata which is parsed at runtime. I am building in a trial licence within the plugin but which will stop the plugin from working when the trial licence has run out. I am unsure of the best way to implement this. MAybe to stop one of the editors opening. I have managed to integrate my licensing software (Protection! from JProductivity), which will get called when the user tries to open on of my editors. But how can I stop an editor from opening?

Any help on this subject would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Editor and its type alway is contributed by extension. So there is no good way to remove this extension besides early startup your bundle. But I don't think it's a good practice.

So the better way is checking your license in **EditorPart.init(IEditorSite, IEditorInput)** or **createPartControl**, throw the exception in **init** call or not create any widget in **createPartControl** if the license is invalid or expired.

Comment: Hi Kane. Yes, I agree about not removing an extension, this was not my intention. I am displaying the error message regarding the license and then I was hoping to stop the editor from opening. If I throw an exception (partInitException) within the init of the editor, the editor will open with an ugly stacktrace being displayed as page contents. I tried to call the close() directly but this caused problems. I also put the close in a "run" so that it executed after the editor opened. The effect was that the user saw the editor open and then it closed immediately. Both not great options.

Comment: @Paul, you could allow users to open your editor. However the editor view displays some words to tell them the license is expired or invalid, and give a hyperlink of your support site. I think it would be friendly.